# Removing duplicate values between two wordpress queries

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I'm addressing a well known issue in Wordpress, in which I want to display "featured" posts, and under it the rest of the posts.
I have a `$query1` which holds 2 featured posts, and my `query_posts` which holds all of the posts on the site (including those two from `$query1`).
I now wish to remove from `query_posts` those two posts so I can display it using regular Wordpress loop in the form of:

```
while (have_posts ()) : the_post();
the_title();
the_content();
endwhile;
```

I have the solution for removing these duplicate posts inside the above loop, but because of the paging, I want to have the query without duplicates before that, so the `query_posts` array will be paged **without** those two featured posts.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good answer for this, based on the wordpress.stackexchange.com - You can find it [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61936/removing-duplicate-values-between-two-wordpress-queries/61940).